# Having trouble with Create-Only rules in Firebase Realtime Database

Tags: json, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-security

I'm trying to create a card deck database.
I have a node, "decks". Inside it are more nodes, numbered from '00001'. Inside '00001' is a node for each card, numbered appropriately, and inside each card node is the card data.

```
deck
    00001
         card001
             SetCode:Alpha
             SetID:001
         card002
             etc.
```

My problem is when it comes to the security rules. I don't want anyone to be able to update or delete any decks.

```
"decks":{      
       "$deckId":{
         ".validate": "$deckId.matches(/^[0-9]{5,5}$/) && $deckId.length == 5 && data.val() == null && newData.val() != null",
           "$cardNumber":{
             ".validate": "$cardNumber.matches(/^[C][a][r][d][0](30|2[0-9]|1[0-9]|[0][1-9])$/) && $cardNumber.length == 7",
               "SetCode":{".validate": "newData.isString()&& newData.val().matches(/^[A-Z][a-z]{4}$/)"},
                             "SetID":{".validate": "newData.isString()&& newData.val().matches(/^[0-9]{3}$/)"},
}}}
```

and I can't seem to find a set of rules that lets me make a new deck while also preventing anyone from deleting it or updating an existing deck.
Some rules I've tried are:

```
".write": "auth != null",
".write": "data.val() == null && newData.hasChildren() != null",
".write": "!data.exists()"
".write": "data.val() == null && newData.val() != null"
```

in various 'depths' of the rules, but I've been hitting my head against this for hours now. If someone could point me to the correct rule in the correct 'depth', I would be very grateful.

Edit: The main instance that I thought would work - and that I had found on multiple resources for Creation-Only rules, was:

```
'decks':{
      ".write": "data.val() == null && newData.val() != null",
      }
```

It could be that I'm putting it in the wrong depth or if there's some other factor I haven't taken into account, but I don't understand why this doesn't work. I don't have any other read/write rules on higher levels.

Comment: Going forward, please don't enumerate everything you tried, but give us the one option that you thought should've worked. In what you shared, the third rule seems like it should reject overwriting existing data. If it didn't do that for you, can you edit your question to show the code that you used?

Comment: Ah, sorry. I'm new to overflow, and firebase. 

".write": "!data.exists()"

prevents deletion and updating, but also prevents creation according to the Rules Playground

edit: didnt realise it was 'hit enter to post'

Answer (score 0):

The problem is where you defined the rule, not their contents.

You need to define the rule on the exact path where the write operation occurs. Since you want to allow creating a new deck, you need the rule to be on the individual deck, which you can do by [using a wildcard variable](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/security/core-syntax#wildcard_capture_variables):

```
'decks':{
  "$deckid": {
    ".write": "!data.exist" // allows creation, but not updating or deletion
  }
}
```

Comment: Well, that definitely makes it work in the Rules Playground. Glad that's sorted, thankyou. 
Follow-up question: When I try to create the same objects outside of the playground (connecting to firebase through Unity), it only creates Card001 and it's SetCode child. If a for() loop to create each card and populate each child object would be seen by Firebase as one Create followed by several Updates, then I may need to look into generating a single .json file through Unity. Is that the case?

Comment: Good to hear this explains the problem you posted in the question. If you have a new problem now, I recommend posting a new question for that with its own [minimal repro](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).